# Tablor package error

Tags: errors

Please what's the error in this code, it didn't work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pst-eps} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[xcas]{tablor} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{TV} TV([-1,1],[],"f","x",x^2,1,n,\tv) \end{TV} 
\end{document}
```

i have this error:

```
./essai tblor.tex:8: FancyVerb Error: Extraneous input ` TV([-1,1],[],"f","x",x^2,1,n,\tv ) \end {TV}' between \beg in{TV}[<key=value>] and line end . \FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error: \space \space #1 } l.8 ... TV([-1,1],[],"f","x",x^2,1,n,\tv) \end{TV} ? Process aborted –
```

Comment: I can't run it because I don't have XCAS; however `\begin{TV}` and `\end{TV}` should be on lines by themselves.

Comment: Which error message do you receive? "Does not work" is not very clear ... BTW: the description of package `tablor` is only in french. It would be a great advantage to have it in English too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried rewriting the line as

```
\begin{TV}
TV([-1,1],[],"f","x",x^2,1,n,\tv)
\end{TV}
```

and rerunning? From looking at the code of tablor it appears to use the `fancyvrb` package, wrapping the parameters in a verbatim environment. Since verbatim environments can't have text following their `\begin` declaration, this should cause your error.

I'm afraid I can't do the actual testing, since I, too, don't have XCAS.

Comment: just a question: why it works with you solution and don't work with \begin{TV} TV([-1,1],[],"f","x",x^2,1,n,\tv) \end{TV} ?